# Fetch data from server in chunks using ember data (like infinite scroll)

Tags: ember.js, asp.net-web-api

I would like to display a very long list of users (yes i suggested pagination but the client wont take it) and i would like to fetch a few records at a time.

This is mainly because creating the list on the server side is resource intensive (every field is encrypted in the database<-- again there is little i can do to change this) and retrieving 1000 records would slow down the app. so i would like to display 30 records and get the next 30 immediately afterwards (the same way infinite scroll works, without having to scroll down to fetch more records). Below is my route handler:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(){
        return this.store.query('user', {
            firstname:'doe' // this comes from a textbox when filtering the list of users
            pageSize:30,
            page:1,
            orderBy:'id'
        });
    }
});
```

To make ember and webapi play nice together, i have implemented everything here https://github.com/CrshOverride/ember-web-api

the api does not return any pagination information, but i would like to keep fetching the next page until the recordset that returns is smaller than pagesize.

Background: Im migrating from angular 1 to ember 2 (very much an ember novice) and i believe i am using ember data and i generate most stuff via ember-cli

Comment: Did you check [ember-infinity addon](https://github.com/hhff/ember-infinity)?

Comment: Yes, but the addon requires the user to scroll to the bottom whereas i want the full list to be shown without user interaction. Secondly the addon expects data in a specific format, e.g. a meta data property called totalpages which i cannot provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that Ember-Data doesn't provide out of the box, but is very easy to implement on your own.

```
// route.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController(controller) {
        controller.fetchUsers(someNameOrAnother);
    }
});

// controller.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    fetchUsers(name) {
        this.set('allUsers', []);
        this.fetchUsersHelper(name);
    },

    fetchUsersHelper(name, page = 1) {
        const queryParams = {
            firstname: name,
            pageSize: 30,
            page,
            orderBy: 'id'
        };

        this.store.query('user', queryParams).then((users) => {
            this.set('allUsers', this.get('allUsers').concat(users.toArray()));

            if (users.get('length')>= queryParams.pageSize) {
                this.fetchUsersHelper(name, queryParams.page + 1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm about to try this out, makes a lot of sense to me, but i get a feeling that the list of users will only be displayed once all users have been fetched. want i would want to do is to display the available users, whilst fetching the rest (and display a loading icon whilst this happens)

Comment: Yes, that is what will happen in this case. But you can easily have it display the users as it loads by moving this logic to the controller. Just move `fetchUsers` to your controller, and make `allUsers` a property on the controller instead of an argument to the function. I'll update my answer with that code.

Comment: works a treat, only change i did was, instead of using '#each model' in the template, i am now using '#each allUsers'. thanx... now im told controllers will be a thing of the past, i will need to figure out how to convert this into 'components' i presume?